# UNION ALL parameterised postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'd like to do something like this in postgres

```sql
select * from table t where t.one = 11 AND t.two = 12 and t.three = 13
union all
select * from table t where t.one = 21 AND t.two = 22 and t.three = 23
```

I tried `join lateral` and `inner join`s but the performance is too bad. So I need to `union all` these queries but I don't want just to concat an indefinate amount of these values, Is there something like these https://stackoverflow.com/a/55484168/1321514 for postgres?

Comment: What do you mean by "indefinate amount of these values"? Which values, where do they come from, and in which ways can they vary? Maybe you should show us your join attempts if they do what you want.

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL has standard `unnest`. Did you try to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the need for a UNION at all. And I don't understand how a JOIN would help here

Your query is equivalent to:

```
select * 
from table t 
where (t.one,t.two,t.three) in ( (11,12,13), (21,22,23) );
```

Alternatively you can try joining to a VALUES clause:

```
select t.* 
from table t 
  join (
     values (11,12,13), (21,22,23) 
  ) as x(c1,c2,c3) on t.one = x.c1 
                  and t.two = x.c2
                  and t.three = x.c3;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: is it possible to do this using java with jdbc? thanks

Comment: @otonakav: yes, of course. Just run that SQL through `Statement.executeQuery()`

Comment: I mean passing the array containing the values for column `one`, another array for column `two` and another array for column `three`,
I was trying to do `select * from table where (one, two, three) in (select * from unnest(array[11,21]::integer[], array[12,22]::integer[], array[13,23]::integer[]))` and then in java setting the arrays with `setArrayOf()` but this destroys the performance @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217068/pass-unknown-number-of-parameters-to-in-clause-using-jdbc-and-postgres