# pass unknown number of parameters to IN clause using JDBC and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, postgresql-11, pg-jdbc

My query looks like this, and performs well:

```sql
select * 
from table t 
where (t.one,t.two,t.three) in ( (11,12,13), (21,22,23) );
```

Now the number of these triplets within the `in` statement will vary, so I'm trying to do the following with JDBC:

```java
String sql = "select * from table where (one, two, three) in (select * from unnest(?::smallint[], ?::integer[], ?::integer[]))"
// conn is the java.sql.Connection
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("smallint", new Short[]{11, 21}));
ps.setArray(2, conn.createArrayOf("integer", new Integer[]{12,22}));
ps.setArray(3, conn.createArrayOf("integer", new Integer[]{13,23}));
return ps;
```

And that performs terribly bad. So is there a way to send the triplets using jdbc such that the end result is equivalent to the sql query?

I'd have two btree indexes one on `one, two` and another on `one, three` I need to use any of those in order to make this performant

Answer (score 0):

You could create a composite type like

```
CREATE TYPE triple AS (
   a smallint,
   b integer,
   c integer
);
```

Then you could write the query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE (t.one, t.two, t.three) = ANY (?::triple[]);
```

You'd supply the array as a single string that looks like

```
{(11\,12\,13), (21\,22\,23)}
```

`= ANY` does the same as `IN`, but it can be used with an array on the right hand side.

Comment: this is even worst since postgres does not use any of the available indexes

Comment: You didn't say that you had indexes. Please add the index definitions to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I could accomplish that using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

```java
String sql = "select * from table " +
        "where (one, two, three) in (:valuesMap)";

List<Integer[]> valuesMap = new ArrayList<>();
valuesMap.add(new Integer[]{11,12,13});
valuesMap.add(new Integer[]{21,22,23});
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("valuesMap", valuesMap);

return jdbc.query(sql, params, resultSetExtractor);
```

This works despite `one` being a `smallint`